# Javascript: Sliding panel from the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, panel, slide

I Search of an Sliding panel from the right.

I am looking for alternatives for this component:

http://pupunzi.com/mb.components/mb.extruder/demo/demo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will require JQuery UI.

```
$('#content').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000, function () {
 //Do what you want when the animation is finished.
});
```

Documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

Comment: I tried your link, its actually pushing the other contents of the page, can't it be used to get the overlay effect?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the panel widget:

https://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/

It has overlay or push options.